# Upload profile photo to strapi collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, strapi

I have a problem uploading a file that is a picture for a user profile in my user collection in strapi.

This is my photo form in react

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Form, Button} from "semantic-ui-react"
import {useFormik} from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import {toast} from "react-toastify";

import {updatePhotoApi} from "../../../api/user";

export default function ChangeNameForm(props){
    const {user, logout,setReloadUser} = props;

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: initialValues(user.photo),
        validationSchema: Yup.object(validationSchema()),
        onSubmit: async (formData) => {
            console.log(formData);
            setLoading(true);
            const response = await updatePhotoApi(user.id, formData,logout);
            console.log(response);
            if(!response) {
                toast.error("Error al actualizar foto ")
            }else{
                setReloadUser(true);
                toast.success("Foto actualizada");
            }
            setLoading(false);
        }
    })
    return (
        <div className="change-name-form">
            <h4>Cambia tu foto</h4>
            <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group widths="equal">
                    <Form.Input 
                    name="photo"
                    type="file"
                    placeholder="Tu nueva foto"
                    error={formik.errors.photo}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    value={formik.values.photo}/>
                </Form.Group>
                <Button className="submit" loading={loading}>Actualizar</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}


function initialValues(photo){
    return {
        photo: photo || "",
        
    }
}

function validationSchema(){
    return {
        photo: Yup.string().required(true),
    }
}
```

and there is the api call

```
    export async function updatePhotoApi(idUser,data,logout){
    
    try {
        const url = `${BASE_PATH}/users/${idUser}`;
        const params = {
            method: "PUT",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json" 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        };
        const result = await authFetch(url,params,logout);
        console.log(result);
        return result ? result : null;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

but im still getting error 505 internal server error, i dont know what im doing wrong, and cant find such information about to do this.

In my collection for user i have the field called photo for the a single img picture, for later show it as a avatar picture in the client

Comment: How did you end up solving the issue? Very few examples of how to do upload media from a custom front end

Comment: At the end ive never did that implementation, but check this video and see if this could work for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2M3pOovhGTk, also here you can check the documentation https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#upload-files-related-to-an-entry